# Pygame platformer enemy movement

Tags: python, pygame

I am working on a platform game and trying to make my enemy move back and forth a certain distance. Basically I need to find a way to increase dis to a certain number, decrease it back to zero, then increase it again back to the same number. It needs to keep doing this indefinitely. Right now it increases to 10 but then stays there. Any help would be much appreciated. (Note: This code is just a test version with all the "self's" removed.)

```
speed  = 1
dis = 0

while True:
    if speed > 0:
        dis += 1
    if dis > 10:
        speed = -1
        dis -= 1            
    if dis < 0:
        speed = 1
    print(dis)
```

Comment: use `print()` to see values in variables and see which part of code is executed. It helps to find mistake. Maybe you have to add variables like `increase_speed = True`, `decrease_speed = False` or `state = "increasing"`, `state = "decreasing"`  to better control it.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try to break it up? Based on the current distance, set your speed. And then based on the current speed, increment or decrement your distance.

```
speed  = 1
dis = 0

while True:
    if dis >= 10:
        # Set speed
    if dis <= 0:
        # Set speed

    # Based on speed, increment or decrement distance
```

Comment: you could add code in place of `# Set speed` and `# Based` to make it even more useful :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
speed  = 1
dis = 0

while True:
    dis += speed

    if dis >= 10:
        speed = -1
    elif dis <= 0:
        speed = 1
```

`dis += speed` can be before `if/elif` or after `if/elif` to get expected result.

Or you can even use `speed = -speed` to change direction

```
speed  = 1
dis = 0

while True:
    dis += speed

    if dis <= 0 or dis >= 10:
        speed = -speed
```

Comment: Most elegant answer by far.

Comment: This is great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out :)

```
speed  = 1
dis = 0



while True:
    if speed >= 0:
        dis += 1
    if dis >= 10:
        speed = -1            
    if speed <= 0:
        dis -= 1
    if dis <= 0:
        speed = 1
    print(dis)
```

Comment: you  could use one `dis += speed` instead of both `if speed`. If spee will be < 0 then you get `dis += -1`, if speed will be > 0 then you get `dis += 1`

Answer (score 1):

You can just check if the object is outside of the area and then invert the speed. [`pygame.Rect`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)s have a lot of attributes like `left` and `right` which can be helpful here.

```
import pygame as pg


pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pg.time.Clock()
BG_COLOR = pg.Color('gray13')
BLUE = pg.Color('dodgerblue1')

rect = pg.Rect(300, 200, 20, 20)
distance = 150
speed = 1

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True

    # Check if the rect is outside of the specified
    # area and if it's moving to the left or right.
    if (rect.right > 300+distance and speed > 0
            or rect.left < 300 and speed < 0):
        speed *= -1  # Invert the speed.
    # Add the speed to the rect's x attribute to move it.
    rect.x += speed

    # Draw everything.
    screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
    pg.draw.rect(screen, BLUE, rect)
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pg.quit()
```